# IE7/8, jQuery ui sortable, and hiding content. O.o

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, refresh, jquery-ui-sortable

So I've been having weird problems with jQuery sortable. I've got sortable li elements, which sort fine, however in IE, when dragging, the images disappear. I'm fairly sure they just get positioned weirdly but it doesn't seem to happen in any other browsers, other times the whole content within will disapear.

Now I found a fix to this, refreshing the html using;

```
$(this).html($(this).html());
```

This seems to fix the IE crapness, however in other browsers (and not IE), the values of form elements get reset when this is done.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: can you throw up a sample page that shows this bug?  I could take a look at what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to run a javascript function called "ResetHtml()", then define the function in a php file, forcing only IE to do;

```
$(this).html($(this).html());
```

And leaving the other browsers as they were.

Thanks for your suggestions as always :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substring(0,1) <= '7') {
        $(this).html($(this).html());
    }
```

for targeting IE in jQuery.